# System.StackOverflowException when launching application

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

When I launch my application it gives me an error at " Form1 Test = new Form1();" in my class. Here is my code. I want to use labels from my form so therefore I used "form1 test".

I made a class so I can call my methods from it in my Mainform as I need to code my application with classes. When I launched the application for the first time it worked, but then after trying again it didn't work anymore.

Main form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tester
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Zombie zombie = new Zombie();
        int levens = 3;
        


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
           
            test1.Text = "Levens: " + "" + levens;
            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void Zombie()
        {

            foreach (Control control in Controls)
            {
                PictureBox pic = control as PictureBox;
                if (pic != null)
                {
                    pic.Top += 1;
                    if (pic.Top > 600 && pic.Visible == true)
                    {

                        pic.Top = 0;
                        test1.Text = $"Levens: {--levens}";
                    }
                    else if (pic.Top > 600 && pic.Visible == false)
                    {
                        pic.Visible = true;
                        pic.Top = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            zombie.MakeZombie(5, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tester
{
    class Zombie
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Form1 Test = new Form1();
        
        private int score = 0;


        public void MakeZombie(int aantal, Form formInstance)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++)
            {
                PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();
                picture.Image = Properties.Resources.ZombieDik;
                picture.Size = new Size(200, 200);
                picture.Location = new Point(random.Next(1500), 0);
                picture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                picture.Click += zombie_Click;
                picture.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                formInstance.Controls.Add(picture);
            }
        }
        void zombie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox pic = sender as PictureBox;
            pic.Visible = false;
            score++;
            Test.label2.Text = $"Score: {score}";
            Test.Controls.Remove(pic);
            pic.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, makes perfect sense - your application creates a `Form1` on startup, the form then creates an instance of the `Zombie` class, which in turn instantiates a new `Form1` and so on. This happens until there is no stack space left and you get a stack overflow.

Comment: A common mistake: To access the main Form you need a refeence to __it__ not to a __new instance__. Create a Zombie constructor int which you pass a reference to Form1..! Only then will any zombie be removed from the main form..

Comment: The _MakeZombie_ method receives the instance of the form where you want to add the PictureBox. Just save that instance in your internal variable _Test_ and do not create another instance of Form1 because it will start the infinite loop that kills the app.

Comment: Also, not sure if it is a great idea to remove and destroy the control in the same click event raised by the control that you want to destroy. Probably first hide it and then destroy the hidden PictureBoxes in a Timer event

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `zombie_Click()` you can get a reference to the Form from the sender itself:

```
void zombie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pic = sender as PictureBox;                       
    Form1 f1 = pic.FindForm() as Form1;
    score++;
    f1.label2.Text = $"Score: {score}";
    pic.Dispose();
}
```